# Build Ionic Product for Android

Tags: ionic4

After I use `ionic cordova build android --prod` to build android apk, the ionic components can not use, but use `ionic cordova build android` to build apk is ok, please advise...

Comment: Hi @kings. Can you explain the problem you are having in a bit more detail. What do you mean by 'can not use'?

Answer (score 0):

check your dependencies (Cordova)

run this

```
ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss
```